# Serial doesn't initialise on Arduino Mega 2560 when not powered via the USB port

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial

I am working on a project with a Mega 2560 and a Sim800L module.

Everything works fine, however if i don't connect the USB port (at least once) and power only externally (either by Vin unregulated 7-12V or 5V regulated pin)
the program will seem not to initialize serial in setup().

I found this which is related to the issue but not a proper workaround:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=24642.0

edit: I can confirm using a resistor to short pins 0+1 together (serial) works but it is not a proper solution. This means you have to disassemble your project to access the resistor or add a switch if you want to use USB to debug later or upload new code. Another workaround which i need to test is to remove all Serial code (because i can in my specific project), but again this is not a proper solution.
Any ideas please?

edit2: 
for comments

```
if(SIM900.available()>0){
// AT command to set SIM900 to SMS mode
SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
delay(100);
// Set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
delay(100);
textMessage = SIM900.readString();
textMessage.toUpperCase();
Serial.print(textMessage);    
delay(10);
} 

if(textMessage.indexOf("SET PHONE")>=0){
// Set phone number to receive notifications
phoneNumber = textMessage.substring(9,21);
Serial.println("Phone number set to: " + phoneNumber);  
String message = "Notification number set to: " + phoneNumber + "\nSend 'Help' for additional commands.\nNote in case of reset number returns to hardcoded default";
sendSMS(message);
Serial.println("Confirmication of phone number change sent");
textMessage = "";   
}
```

Comment: so why the softwareserial tag? Sim800 is on Serial1/2/3? do you use some old AVR core version or IDE?

Comment: That link is 13 years old and I did not hear about that pin 0/1 trick recently. Do you have such an old Arduino board? Are you sure the USB controller (ATmega16U2 ?) does not get its Vcc HIGH via Vin?

Comment: You did not provide any code, so we have to guess. Do you print to the Serial Terminal on your PC/Laptop in the Sketch. The if you don't connect the Arduino with the PC you do not establish the serial connection to the terminal. Perhaps you added a blocking command, that waits for the connection.   Connecting Pin0 and Pin1 simulates the Terminal connection and the blocking code does not block. If I'm right, a solution would be to remove the blocking code. But I don't know code, so I can't tell you how,

Comment: @juraj Because i use softwareserial to connect to sim800. I converted it to hardware serial as a test and it works but needs some more changes

Comment: @DataDiffler My board is not old, i can check if that's the case

Comment: @Peter Paul Kiefer Yes i print without checks. Some parts of the code in loop work so it doesn't make sense for me to need checks. In fact the part that doesn't seem to work checks for softwareserial buffer, not serial so i don't think there is any blocking. Here's an example of the non-working part of the code (didn't debug if both of the blocks don't work):

Comment: I would be more interested in the setup method. Where the `Serial.begin`  is located and all location where Serial is used. Perhaps a `while ( ! Serial.available() )` or something else. Can you switch the onboard LED to ON in the first if block above, to see if it is entered at all. And the Software serial can also stop the program and wait for a connection.

Comment: Nothing special other than setting initial values and pins, just Serial.begin(57600);  and  SIM900.begin(57600);. I could use while (! Serial); everytime i want to print but i believe this doesn't work on Mega, right?

Comment: @DataFiddler Checked (i have 2 here) both are clones using the C340G instead of ATmega16U2 for UART to USB and it is powered normally. Problem is that if i have serial.print functions seem to make the program not able to function normally unless serial is connected. Functions inside the program that don't have serial.print code in them (like sendsms function) work normally and the loop continues to work.

Comment: never use SoftwareSerial on Mega (it is not the cause of your problem, only something that doesn't make sense)

Comment: the ATmega2560 doesn't know if USB is connected. it sends the data and doesn't care what happens with it. there is no UART flow control to block the transmitting.

Comment: @juraj yeah i already converted it today to use hardware serial, i just used software serial since i knew it should work 100%. I know mega2560 doesn't know if usb is connected but i don't know why serial.print will break the program if it's not connected to anything. They say it's because the RX0 pin is floating when not connected. So is there is a way to keep serial.print inside the code and ignore it when not connected?

Comment: I think i know a bodge solution..wire the DTR pin into one of the digital inputs and read it when i want to print in serial..

Comment: RX and TX of ATmega2560 is connected to the USB chip's RX and TX and this connection is active. no floating pins

Comment: @Juraj After doing several checks with Serial disabled and running functions to check if DTR is open or closed i found the issue wasn't caused by this. Posted explanation and answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the issue and the solution.

For some reason it seems that while the MCU is running Setup(); hardware or software serial don't work properly.

In my case i have code that set the SIM module to SMS mode and to send those messages to the serial port.

For some reason it doesn't send them (or probably the module is not ready to accept them).

Connecting the USB cable reset the arduino and run setup() when opening the serial monitor setting the module in the correct mode.

Adding this code in the main loop solves this issue even though i have them powered both by the same step down converter.

edit: That turns out 1 hour later after debugging more is not exactly a proper solution to the issue.
 That command to set into SMS mode only works when you are connected to the network.

I have a check for that and a reset function.

So now at Setup() i wait 10s for the module to boot up so it is ready to open a serial port, then i check if it is connected to the network before i send the commands to set into SMS mode.

Example:

```
// Initializing serial commmunication
Serial.begin(57600); 
delay(10000);

while (ini){
    Serial3.begin(57600);
    delay(1000);
    Serial3.print("AT+CGREG?\r"); 
    delay(100);
    netStatus = Serial3.readString();
    if (netStatus.charAt(22) == '5' || netStatus.charAt(22) == '1') {
         digitalWrite(LED_NET, HIGH);
         ini=false;
         }
    else {  
        digitalWrite(LED_NET, LOW);
        digitalWrite(resetPin, LOW);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(resetPin, HIGH);
        delay(30000);
        }
}
  Serial.print("SIM800 ready...");

  // AT command to set SIM800 to SMS mode
  Serial3.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
  delay(100);
  // Set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
  Serial3.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
  delay(100);
```